# When using R package circlize to draw a PDF image , there will be redundant lines, why? How to eliminate redundant lines

Tags: r, circlize

I used the R package circlize to draw a PDF image (Figure 1)[fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feboo.png). The display of images viewed through R studio zoom and WPS(a type of PDF reader) is shown in Figure 1. However, when I opened the PDF through AI, a large number of redundant lines appeared, as shown in Figure 2[fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhZ3u.jpg). The details of redundant lines were shown in Figure 3[fig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UveTR.jpg). What is the reason? How to solve it?

The body code of my drawing is as follows (some coloring related code or data are not shown)：

```
library(circlize) 
library(reshape2)
library(ComplexHeatmap) 
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gap_size <- c(rep(0.8, length(all_otu) - 1), 6, rep(0.8, length(all_sample) - 1), 6)
circos.par(cell.padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0), start.degree = 270, gap.degree = gap_size)
circos.initialize(factors = factor(all_ID, levels = all_ID), xlim = all_ID_xlim)

circos.trackPlotRegion(
    ylim = c(0, 1), track.height = 0.03, 
    bg.border = NA, 
    panel.fun = function(x, y) {
        sector.index = get.cell.meta.data('sector.index')
        xlim = get.cell.meta.data('xlim')
        ylim = get.cell.meta.data('ylim')
    } )

for (i in 1:length(tax_phylum)) {
    tax_OTU <- {subset(taxonomy, phylum == tax_phylum[i])}$OTU_ID
    highlight.sector(tax_OTU, track.index = 1, col = color_otu[i], 
                     text = tax_phylum[i], 
                     facing = "clockwise",cex = 0.5, text.col = 'black', niceFacing = T)
}

for (i in 1:length(all_group)) {
    group_sample <- {subset(group, group_ID == all_group[i])}$sample_ID
    highlight.sector(group_sample, track.index = 1, col = color_sample[i], 
                     text = all_group[i], 
                     facing = "clockwise",cex = 0.7, text.col = 'black',niceFacing = T)
}

link_color <- character(nrow(plot_data))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(plot_data))) {
  group_index <- match(plot_data[i,1], group[,1])
  color_index <- group[group_index, 2]
  link_color[i] <- color_sample[color_index]

    circos.link(
      plot_data[i,1], c(accum_sample[as.character(plot_data[i,1])], accum_sample[as.character(plot_data[i,1])] - plot_data[i,4]),
      plot_data[i,2], c(accum_otu[as.character(plot_data[i,2])], accum_otu[as.character(plot_data[i,2])] - plot_data[i,3]),
      #col = paste0(color_otu[plot_data[i,2]], '70'), border = NA )
        col = paste0(link_color[i], '75'), border = NA )
    accum_otu[as.character(plot_data[i,2])] = accum_otu[as.character(plot_data[i,2])] - plot_data[i,4]
    accum_sample[as.character(plot_data[i,1])] = accum_sample[as.character(plot_data[i,1])] - plot_data[i,3]
}
```

all_ID,chr[1:156]

```
> all_ID
  [1] "hg_bin.256"                                                
  [2] "fg_bin.37"                                                 
  [3] "hg_bin.189"                                                
  [4] "hg_bin.230"                                                
  [5] "hg_bin.257"
```

all_ID_xlim,156 obs. of 2 variables

```
> all_ID_xlim                                                        rep(0, length(all_ID))
hg_bin.256                                                                      0
fg_bin.37                                                                       0
hg_bin.189                                                                      0
hg_bin.230                                                                      0
hg_bin.257                                                                      0
hg_bin.258                                                                      0
hg_bin.112                                                                      0
```

plot_data,6075 obs. of 4 variables

```
> head(plot_data)
                    sample_ID     otu_ID value value.1
1   aminoglycoside__aac(2')-I hg_bin.256     0       0
82   aminoglycoside__aac(3)-I hg_bin.256     0       0
163          bacitracin__bacA hg_bin.256     1       1
244         beta-lactam__ampC hg_bin.256     0       0
325        beta-lactam__CfxA2 hg_bin.256     0       0
406        beta-lactam__CfxA3 hg_bin.256     0       0
```

tax_phylum

```
> tax_phylum
 [1] p__Firmicutes_A     p__Bacteroidota     p__Proteobacteria  
 [4] other               p__Actinobacteriota p__Firmicutes      
 [7] p__Planctomycetota  p__Cyanobacteria    p__Firmicutes_C    
[10] p__Fusobacteriota  
10 Levels: p__Firmicutes_A p__Bacteroidota p__Proteobacteria ... p__Fusobacteriota
```

all_group,chr[1:16]

```
> head(all_group)
[1] "aminoglycoside"  "bacitracin"      "beta-lactam"    
[4] "chloramphenicol" "fosfomycin"      "fosmidomycin"
```

group，75 obs. of 2 variables

```
> head(group)
                  sample_ID       group_ID
1 aminoglycoside__aac(2')-I aminoglycoside
2  aminoglycoside__aac(3)-I aminoglycoside
3          bacitracin__bacA     bacitracin
4         beta-lactam__ampC    beta-lactam
5        beta-lactam__CfxA2    beta-lactam
6        beta-lactam__CfxA3    beta-lactam
```

taxonomy，81 obs. of 8 variables

```
> head(taxonomy)
       OTU_ID     kingdom          phylum         class
2  hg_bin.256 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
4   fg_bin.37 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
14 hg_bin.189 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
16 hg_bin.230 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
18 hg_bin.257 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
19 hg_bin.258 d__Bacteria p__Firmicutes_A c__Clostridia
                order                family            genus
2   o__Lachnospirales    f__Lachnospiraceae g__Eubacterium_G
4   o__Lachnospirales    f__Lachnospiraceae g__Acetatifactor
14  o__Lachnospirales    f__Lachnospiraceae       g__CAG-510
16  o__Lachnospirales    f__Lachnospiraceae       g__Dorea_A
18  o__Lachnospirales    f__Lachnospiraceae g__Eubacterium_G
19 o__Oscillospirales f__Acutalibacteraceae g__Eubacterium_R
                         species
2   s__Eubacterium_G sp000434315
4  s__Acetatifactor intestinalis
14        s__CAG-510 sp000434615
16      s__Dorea_A longicatena_B
18   s__Eubacterium_G ventriosum
19  s__Eubacterium_R sp000434995
```

At the same time, I also tried to export the file in eps format using R studio and open it using AI. The AI suggested that I lacked Helvetica font and all lines were not displayed (see Figure 4)[fig4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxuwW.png). After I installed Helvetica font and opened it using AI, no font error was reported, but the image preview was still the same as that in Figure 4.

When I use the example data and the example code, there are no redundant lines, so I am more confident that it is my code error, or my own data overload？

Comment: Your use of "AI" in your question is unclear, and requires further details. Are you referring to Artificial Intelligence, or Adobe Illustrator?